# QGIS export coords on mouse click in file

Tags: export, coordinates, qgis

I am trying to export the coordinates a user left-clicks in QGIS to a simple txt file automatically (I need to get this info to my labview VI) but have been unsucessfull yet, any ideas?

Copilot proposed

`canvas = iface.mapCanvas()`
`def display_point(point, button):`
    `coords = "{}, {}".format(point.x(), point.y())`
    `with open('coordinates.txt', 'a') as f:`
        `f.write(coords + '\n')`
`canvas.xyCoordinates.connect(display_point)``

but no idea what "button" should be, I do not know python